# In Online Exam,How I Will Show The Next quest and ans After Clicking The Next Button.I Can Show Only The First quest

Tags: asp.net, database, entity-framework

The code I have so far tried

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Time();
        Question();
    }

    }
    public void Question()
    {
        int res2 = Convert.ToInt32(lblsubject.Text);
        var res3 = (from test in obj.Quest where test.subid == res2 select test).FirstOrDefault();
        if (res3 != null)
        {
            lblqst.Text = res3.question;
            opt1.Text = res3.answ1;
            opt2.Text = res3.answ2;
            opt3.Text = res3.answ3;
            opt4.Text = res3.answ4;
        }
      }
      protected void btn_next_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {

        /*what code to use here?this is the next button where after clicking it next question will display*/
       }
```

Comment: There is a [wizard control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w7dyf6b5%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX) in asp.net may be it can help you.Other wise you can use a random number to pick the question and then use that question in you page. Maintain session for answer and question.

Comment: Here is a sample link http://1000projects.org/online-examination-project-in-asp-net-source-code.html